# Wireless Connection doesn't work without Windows Shell

Tags: windows-shell

We run a dedicated application on Windows XP and disable the shell to prevent users from accessing the Windows features.
When we switched to wireless network, the card doesn't work until we start the shell.
Is there a way to make it work without the shell?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry that this doesn't work on  XP, but win Vista and up van.dll will work:

```
rundll32 van.dll,RunVANW
```